nvme-tcp module missing
I installed ubuntu in a vm using cloud-init and the 22.04 minimal cloud image. It turns out that it doesn't have nvme-tcp module installed.
uname -a
Linux adm-st3 5.15.0-1059-kvm #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 15:41:51 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Is this because of the "minimal" version of the os?  I am using the minimal version for kubernetes cluster nodes.  I am installing mayastor storage and it requires nvme-tcp.
I have ensured that the modules package is installed.
root@adm-st3:/lib/modules/5.15.0-1059-kvm# apt install linux-modules-5.15.0-1059-kvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-modules-5.15.0-1059-kvm is already the newest version (5.15.0-1059.64).
linux-modules-5.15.0-1059-kvm set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Whats the best way to solve this? Hate to use the full distro.

Try installing linux-image-extras for your kernel version.
